Iterating a Huggingface Dataset from disk using Generator seems broken. How to do it properly?
I have a strange behavior in HuggingFace Datasets. My minimal reproduction is as below.
# main.py
import datasets
import numpy as np

generator = np.random.default_rng(0)
X = np.arange(1000)
ds = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(
    mapping={"X":X},
    )
ds.save_to_disk("tmp")
print("First loop")
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(ds.shuffle(generator=generator).iter(batch_size=1)), end=", ")
print("")

print("Second loop")
ds = datasets.Dataset.load_from_disk("tmp")
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(ds.shuffle(generator=generator).iter(batch_size=1)), end=", ")
print("")

The first time I run the script it all looks good. I get a new random iterate every time.
The second time I run the script, the first loop does the same as before, but the second loop is stuck at sample 741. See output below.
$ python main.py
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 598502.28 examples/s]
First loop
{'X': [459]}, {'X': [739]}, {'X': [72]}, {'X': [943]}, {'X': [241]}, {'X': [181]}, {'X': [845]}, {'X': [830]}, {'X': [896]}, {'X': [334]}, 
Second loop
{'X': [741]}, {'X': [847]}, {'X': [944]}, {'X': [795]}, {'X': [483]}, {'X': [842]}, {'X': [717]}, {'X': [865]}, {'X': [231]}, {'X': [840]}, 
$ python main.py
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 492231.43 examples/s]
First loop
{'X': [459]}, {'X': [739]}, {'X': [72]}, {'X': [943]}, {'X': [241]}, {'X': [181]}, {'X': [845]}, {'X': [830]}, {'X': [896]}, {'X': [334]}, 
Second loop
{'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, {'X': [741]}, 

If I delete the dataset folder rm -rf tmp then I can run the code once with expected behavior, and it fails again the second time. So it has something to do with persisting the dataset to disk.
What am I doing wrong?

The shuffling is cached. The second time the program is ran, it finds the cache and uses it. When using the cache, the rng state is not advanced, so subsequent calls in the loop return the same shuffle again and again. For reasons I don't understand, the caching is not 'active' for the first loop.
